# Bash: use an alias in a filepath

Tags: bash

I cannot seem to figure out how to use an alias for a filename in a path. For example:

```
alias a="ls /tmp/ -tr | tail -n 1"
cat /tmp/a
```

The alias gives me the name of the most recent file written in `/tmp/`. Then I try to `cat` that file and I get `cat: /tmp/a: No such file or directory`.

When I just type `a` I get the right thing, for instance `some_log_I_just_wrote_to.log`.

Obviously what I *want* is for `cat /tmp/a` to be translated into `cat /tmp/some_log_I_just_wrote_to.log` so that I can see the log.

Any ideas on what the right way to do this is? I sometimes get tangled up in bash with when to use aliases and symlinks and just plain variables, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Aliases aren't expanded in parameters, only when used as a command.

Comment: Instead of using `alias` make it a function like `function a() {ls /tmp/ -tr | tail -n 1}` and then call it like normal command substitution example: `cat /tmp/$(a)`

Comment: try `cat /tmp/$(a)`

Answer (score 0):

Create the alias with

```
alias a='ls /tmp/ -tr | tail -n 1'
```

Use the alias with cat

```
cat $(echo -n /tmp/ && a)
```